# Parse Serve successful beforeSave returns "Object Not Found" error for some users

Tags: parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I have a mobile app which updates a Parse object by incrementing a numeric field.  For a couple of users that update is returning an "Object Not Found" error result.

When looking at the server logs, I see a successful beforeSave for the object immediately followed by an indication of the "Object Not Found" error.

[32minfo[39m: beforeSave triggered for Timeslot for user Kd06Glks3q:
  Input: {... (truncated)
  Result: {"object":{"current":{"__op":"Increment","amount":1},"organizationId":"5KK3RckkmD","available":true}} className=Timeslot, triggerType=beforeSave, user=Kd06Glks3q
[31merror[39m: Error generating response. ParseError { code: 101, message: 'Object not found.' } code=101, message=Object not found.
[31merror[39m: Object not found. code=101, message=Object not found.

This only seems to happen with certain Parse users (2 so far).  Other users performing the same operation succeed and the log shows the afterSave completing immediately after the beforeSave. I have set the VERBOSE environment variable to 1 but didn't see any additional data.

I am running Parse Server 2.7.4

Anyone seeing this type of issue?

Comment: The only time I've seen error 101 is a Parse.Query.get(), which indicates an object with the passed in object id does not exist, or is at least not fetchable by the user. Are they saving an object that was somehow deleted? Or are they saving an object that they do not have find / get permissions for?

Comment: The Timeslot object exists (is not deleted) and the user fetched it in the first place, so seems to have proper access.  There is a fetch of a related object in the beforeSave itself, but there are log messages letting me know that the fetch completes successfully.  There are actually log messages that show up in the logs all the way up to the response.success() call in beforeSave and the log above indicates beforeSave executes successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the object in question had an ACL that pointed to a missing Role object.  I believe this lead to the Parse Server reporting "Object Not Found" error when it tried to apply the ACLs before actually saving the data.  Would be nice if the Parse Error returned actually referenced the class and id of the object that was not found...